# How can I use a batch file to run Vagrant commands, but leave me connected to Vagrant once finished?

Tags: django, batch-file, vagrant

Here's what I have in the batch file so far:

```
set root="C:\Users\esohlberg\lwebsite"
cd %root%
vagrant up
vagrant ssh -- -t "source lw/bin/activate && cd /vagrant/; ./manage.py runserver 0.0.0.0:8000"
cmd /k
```

Once Vagrant is up, I activate a virtualenv, cd into the right place, and run a server. Executing this takes me all the way to the server running, where I can see

```
System check identified no issues (0 silenced).
August 24, 2018 - 12:33:12
Django version 2.0.3, using settings 'lwebsite.settings'
Starting development server at http://0.0.0.0:8000/
Quit the server with CONTROL-C.
```

However, as soon as I quit with CONTROL-C, I see

```
Connection to 127.0.0.1 closed.
```

and I'm no longer in Vagrant. Is it possible to set up the commands in such a way that once the server is quit, I stay in the /vagrant/ directory with the connection still up and Vagrant's virtualenv still active? This would allow me to manage the site or run the server again with less hassle.

I've already looked at https://www.vagrantup.com/docs/provisioning/shell.html, but the examples seem to show commands executed only during provisioning, which I don't want to do every single time I execute this file.

Comment: Taking a look at the `Start` command usage information, _(`Start /?` at the Command Prompt)_, you may be able to use `Start /B` which will start application without creating a new window and where the application has ^C handling ignored. _Unless the application enables ^C processing, ^Break is the only way to interrupt the application._

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I created three .bat files to start, stop vagrant and connect over ssh.

For starting vagrant, also added this to auto run when Windows starting:

```
cd /d "C:\Homestead"
start vagrant up
```

For stoping vagrant:

```
@echo off
cd /d "C:\Homestead"
start vagrant halt
```

And for connecting to local server over ssh

```
cd /d "C:\Homestead"
vagrant ssh
```

Answer (score 0):

> I've already looked at https://www.vagrantup.com/docs/provisioning/shell.html, but the examples seem to show commands executed only during provisioning, which I don't want to do every single time I execute this file.

You've been looking at the right place, what you want is to run the command when the VM starts so you can do the following:

```
config.vm.provision "shell", :inline => "source lw/bin/activate && cd /vagrant/; ./manage.py runserver 0.0.0.0:8000", :run => 'always', :privileged => false
```

That will make sure that every time you're calling `vagrant up` from your host, it will start your python server (as vagrant user)

This way you do not need the script anymore and can just start your VM normally using `vagrant up`

Comment: Is there any way to have the server be started when calling vagrant ssh, instead of vagrant up?

Comment: not really and still its much better to run it through `vagrant up` you start VM and your server is up, you can do from your host machine, you dont even need to ssh into the VM